# How to find square root of 2 and homomorphisms in the quotient ring $L=\frac{\mathbb{F_{5}[x]}}{(x^{2}+2x-1)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I am trying to work through the following problem.

Suppose we are considering the field $$L=\frac{\mathbb{F_{5}[x]}}{(x^{2}+2x-1)}$$ (where $F_{5}$ is $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$)

We also note it is indeed a field as $f(x)=x^2+2x-1$ is irreducible in F.

Then I am wanting to find the square root of two in L, and denote is as z,

then show that

$\beta : \mathbb{F[x]} \to L$ defined by $x \to z$ is a ring homomorphism, and find the kernel of $\beta$ and finally to show it induced an isomorphism $$\frac{\mathbb{F[x]}}{(x^2-2)} \cong L$$

My thoughts;

To me , I thought that L is a field with $25$ elements, and each is of the form $ax+b$ where $a, b\in \mathbb{F_{5}}$

So to me , finding the root of two is like asking which of these elements squared gives us 2.

I also know we can write $x^{2}=1+3x$ in L.

So I just tried squaring some of these elements, and I wasn't getting anywhere, so I thought there must be a much better way to do it.

I thought maybe I could write $(ax+b)(ax+b)=a^{2}x^{2}+2abx+b^{2}=a^{2}(1+3x)+2abx+b^{2}=(3a^{2}+2ab)x+(a^{2}+b^{2})=2$
and then solve $3a^{2}+2ab=0$ and $a^{2}+b^{2}=0$ as a system of equations, as pointed out below, after I fixed the typo this leads me to

$z=(x+1)$ or $z=(x-1)=(x+4)$

Now I am interested in the next part, I will choose $z=(x+1)$ to be the z we refer to now.

I know for it to be a homomorphism it must satisfy ;

$\beta(1)=1$

$\beta(ab)=\beta(a)\beta(b)$

$\beta(a+b)=\beta(a)+\beta(b)$

But here I am already confused, so the identity in F is just $1$ and we are saying $1 \to (x+1)$ so if it is a homomorphism it must be that $(x+1)$ is the identity of L. Is this true? Is not the identity of $L$ $1+I=1+(x^2+2x-1)$

So now I have been told that actually it just sends that x,

so $0x+1 \to 1 $ under the map and the other requirements can be verified.

But how can I find $Ker(\beta)$? I know it is $=\{a \in F : \beta(a)=0_{L}\}$
 but isnt $0_{L}=I$ , so the kernel consists of anything that gets sent to I? Is this even the correct approach? If anyone at all can comment please do so.

But now I am just confused, for how is this a map if we only know what it does to x? what about $x^{2}$ for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a field $F=\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$, where $p(x)=x^2+2x-1$ (Note that this polynomial has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ so $F$ is a field). Indeed in $F$ you have $x^2=3x+1$. Your approach  to calculate the $\sqrt{2}$ is correct, but you have little mistake: $(ax+b)^2=a^2x^2+2abx+b^2 = a^2(1+3x)+2abx+b^2= x(3a^2+2ab)+a^2+b^2=2$. Solving the system of equations gives $a=\pm 1$ and $b= \pm 1$. And indeed $(\pm x \pm 1)^2=2$ in $F$.

For the second part: You have chosen $z=x+1$. So now you have map $\beta: \mathbb{F}_5[x]\rightarrow L$, $x \mapsto x+1$. To see this is a ring homomorphism note that for $a,b \in \mathbb{F}_5[x]$ you have $\beta(a+b)=\beta(r(x)+q(x))=r(x+1)+q(x+1)=\beta(r(x))+\beta(q(x))=\beta(a)+\beta(b)$ (Here I just denoted $a=r(x) \text{ and } b=q(x)$). (I think you can check the other conditions yourself) So indeed we have ring homomorphism which has kernel Ker$(\beta)=\{p(x) \in \mathbb{F}_5[x] \, | \, \beta(p(x))=0_L\}$. So which elements of $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$ will map to $0_L$? Indeed the answer is $\langle x^2-2 \rangle$. Now apply the isomorphism theorem..

Comment: Thanks for catching my mistake. I read my question again and yes I only need to choose one, so say I chose (x+1), then do I verify homommorphism with such?

Comment: @Quality Well two fields with same cardinality are isomorphic and its enough to note that $x^2-2 $ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_5$. If you cant use this fact you can also find the homomorphism explicitely.

Comment: I am somewhat confused for example with even the identity, for example I must send 1 to (x+1), but how is (x+1) the identity of L?

Comment: @Quality the map sends $x$ to $x+1$. So it doesnt do anything to elements without $x$. Here $x$ isnt a variable, its element of the field.

Comment: So it just sends 1 to 1 as this is same as 0x+1 ?

Comment: @Quality Yes. I can put more details tomorrow, currently answering with phone.

Comment: Thank you, that would be great

Comment: The mapping really just maps root of a polynomial $p(x)$ to root of $x^2-2$.

Comment: How so? Im not sure I follow that, for example, if x sends to (x+1) then I understand x sends to a root of $x^{2}-2$ but how do we know it sends roots of p(x) to it? Which is p(x)?

Comment: Yes I am really not so sure what p(x) is meant

Comment: @Quality I actually misread the second part (forget the $p(x)$). I'll try to fill in more details in few hours.

Comment: @Quality I added some hints to the second part.

Comment: Thank you, could you please let me know again how I can see that x^2-2 is in the  ker, I think I am having trouble understanding the map. For example, (x^2-2) gets mapped to what?

Comment: @Quality $\beta(x^2-2) = [(x+1)^2-2]_L = 0_L$

Comment: Thanks for all your help !